# How do you find a date range for each price value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that contains an item_id, subcategories, the days it was sold, the amount sold and its price for that day.
For example:

```
item_id     subcategory1     subcategory2     date                 price    quantity
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-03             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-03             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-06             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-06             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-09             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-13             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-13             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-20             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-21             2.665       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-21             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-22             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-22             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-25             2.970       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-27             2.665       1
AB1342         sub1             sub2        2020-04-28             2.970       1
```

The output should be

```
item_id    subcategory1     subcategory2     price   start_date    end_date     quantity
AB1342       sub1              sub2           2.970   2020-04-01   2020-04-20       8
AB1342       sub1              sub2           2.665   2020-04-21   2020-04-21       1
AB1342       sub1              sub2           2.970   2020-04-21   2020-04-21       1
AB1342       sub1              sub2           2.970   2020-04-22   2020-04-26       3
AB1342       sub1              sub2           2.970   2020-04-27   2020-05-31       2
```

The period is between April 1st, 2020 to May 31st, 2020. if there is no transaction after April 1st, then it is assumed to be the price that was first mentioned, in this case, it is 2.97.

Comment: your question is not clear? can you add some explanation how you are getting expected output?

Comment: I apologize, I just want the range for each price, for example, from April 1st to April 20th the item's price was 2.97 and it sold 8 units. It's sort of like a groupby but I tried it but getting that date  range is what I'm struggling with

Comment: looks like your preparing your df for a survival analysis. Is that your goal? If so, why are there multiple occurences per day?

Answer (score 1):

I would try it with the `groupby` function of dataframe.
I have not understood if the period should be coherent or not, so this is just an idea for a solution.
Get all combinations of item_id, subcategories with groupby

```
df.groupby(['item_id','subcategory1','subcategory2','price']).apply(Func1)
```

The function `Func1` must be defined with respect to your problem.
If you just need the first and last day, you can use the agg-function for the date column like

```
df.groupby(['item_id','subcategory1','subcategory2','price']).agg({'date': 'min', 'date': 'max'})
```

I hope this will help you to getting closer to the solution of your problem